# How to include SFML source code into my visual studio 2017 c++ project and compile

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compilation, sfml

I have been programming a game in c++ using the sfml library. However, I would like to adjust some of the code of that library, and use that altered code in my project.

So instead of linking the dll I would like to add the source code and then play with that source code. (e.g. for speed optimization).

I know that doing something like that is generally speaking a bad idea. Howeover, I want to learn by playing around a bit and trying different things.

So how would I add the sfml source code to my c++ project in MS visual studio. Note that I am a total noob. I already tried adding the sfml folder that I downloaded from git in the project properties page called "Additional Include Directories", but i am getting errors, of the form "Cannot open include file: 'SFML/Graphics/GLCheck.hpp': No such file or directory" so I guess that i have not yet done enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to modify the source code in the library, all you'd have to do is just navigate to where you have SFML installed and go into the code files with a text editor and edit them.

Then, you could link the library to your VS project the same way you would normally but that library is now modified by you.

Seeing as you have a search directory issue already in VS, you must fix that first. Fix that and then go and modify the library's .hpp, .h, .cpp, whatever files in-place.

To fix the search issue.... I don't use VS for graphics, I use CodeBlocks so I am not sure about their GUI to link libraries and change search directories... but, find out where you installed SFML. Check your /usr/include/, it's probably there. Specify that path in the search directories. Just go and find where that GLCheck.hpp file is located. For Example: Say it's full path is /usr/include/SFML/Graphics/GLCheck.hpp... then /usr/include/SFML/Graphics/ or just /usr/include/ (VS might handle it recursively) needs to be in the list of SEARCH DIRECTORIES.